# calling AccountManager#getAuthTokenByFeatures from multiple WorkerThreads at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, android-workmanager, accountmanager

**Background**
I am using `AccountManager` with a custom account type. In the beginning the App starts the user LogInActivity and a token recieved by the server is stored within the account. The tokens are used by some `Worker` organized by `WorkManager` to sync data in the background. Each worker is requesting the token with `AccountManager#getAuthTokenByFeatures()`. When the user is changing the password on the website connected with the server, the token is expired and the `AccountManager` is starting (due to password change) the related LogInActivtiy.

**Issue** If during the user input of the new login data other (parallel running) `Worker` are requesting an AuthToken, the LogInActivity is started multiple times.

**Solution Approach**

1. Setting `android:launchmode="singleInstance"`of LogInActivity -> only one Activity is started, but second, third, ... calling `Worker` results in deadlock due to no return of `AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>`.
2. Creating Workaround: `AccountAthenticator` checks if an Instance of `LogInActivity` is allready running in Foreground and starts all further Activities invisible in the background. If LogIn was successfull all in the background running LogInActivities recieving necessary Information via `LocalBroadcastManager` -> `LocalBroadcastManager` is deprecated, power consuming and unnecessary overhead

Is the use of `AccountManager` in combination with `WorkManager` correct in this case?
Might there any configuration issue with `AccountManager` causing this behavior?
Any other solution approaches?

Help is really appreciated. Thank you!